# Why does Ubuntu ask for my password BEFORE the login screen?

Tags: 20.04, password

When I turn on my Ubuntu 20.04, the startup script that starts a couple of services launches.

The last service started is the `systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service`.
After that, I'm asked to enter my password.

The thing is that after entering my password, I got redirected to the usual login screen where I must enter my password again.

More important, when the password is asked when the service starts, I can enter a wrong password and I will be redirect to the login screen anyway. Waiting a few minutes without entering anything redirects me as well.

I would like to know why my password is asked before the login screen and how to disable this.

Thank you.

**Edit**: I just did an `apt upgrade` and the password-ask war prompt again. Here is a sample of my terminal when I did the upgrade (I dual booted my computer with W10 as well as you can see):

```bsh
Setting up google-chrome-stable (88.0.4324.182-1) ...
Setting up gnupg-l10n (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up friendly-recovery (0.2.41ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
using custom appearance settings
Found background image: /home/mike/Pictures/Wallpapers/arc_dark_wallpaper.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-59-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Enter Auth Password: *  # I put a random single character and I didn't got any error
Setting up gpgconf (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gpg (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gnupg-utils (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gpg-agent (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gpgsm (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up dirmngr (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.98.9.4) ...
Setting up gnupg-agent (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gpg-wks-server (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up gpg-wks-client (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.98.9.4) ...
Setting up gnupg (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up software-properties-gtk (0.98.9.4) ...
```

Comment: From the `systemd-ask-password` manpage: "*The purpose of this tool is to query system-wide passwords — that is passwords not attached to a specific user account. Examples include: unlocking encrypted hard disks when they are plugged in or at boot, entering an SSL certificate passphrase for web and VPN servers.*" Anything you installed around the time this behavior began?

Comment: @user535733 I don't think I did. Is there a way to check that? My disk is not encrypted, I use NordVPN but it doesn't ask for my password in the boot script usually. I have another computer with the exact same configuration and there, I don't have any password asked.
Edit: I actually had it during an `apt upgrade`. I will add this to my question.